# Inherited constructors and "explicit is better than implicit"

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

A well-known principle of good programming style says: "explicit is better than implicit". Don't inherited constructors go against this principle? (A single `using` statement that includes all the constructors of the base class isn't very explicit, is it?)

Comment: Well, to me it sounds quite explicit to me, while avoiding a lot of typing...

Comment: There is a ton of conflicting principles, all of which have both upsides and downsides. For example, configuration by convention and dependency injection are as implicit as it gets, yet they also have their place.

Comment: `short s = 10;`... and then  `int i = s;` .. Here `short` is being *implicitly* converted into `int`  .. **and** it is good.

Comment: Up to a certain point, concise is better than verbose. After that point concision becomes more about "clever" than clear. Still, the implicit is generally more concise. It's a balance, with "what people are used to seeing" being, while totally non-technical, very important.

Comment: Don't words following "well known principle" usually tend to describe unproven  or over-generalized opinions ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this principle is for [`explicit` keyword with constructors and conversion operators](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-7/episode-five-explicit-is-better-than-implicit), not for *explicitely* typing a lot of code. `using` won't change whether the constructors are explicit or implicit.

This principle is (as most principles in C++) also quite disputable and over-generalized.